# Can we store the records in temp table using while loop in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a scenario to store the records in temp table using while loop like below.

**For Example**

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=5)
BEGIN
    PRINT @intFlag
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    select @intFlag datas
    into #tempped
END
GO
```

Is it possible to do like this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results will help answering this question (and in fact, all sql questions).

Comment: did you just try it? i guess its working

Comment: @EstebanP. it will never work. It will show error msg `There is already an object named '#tempped' in the database`

Comment: @mohamedfaiz the error msg says it all: you have to drop your temp table if exists

Comment: @EstebanP. brother If I drop the table. then what is the use of temp table. if i drop the table. then the old record will not be there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the temporary table and `insert` into it from the loop. e.g.:

```
create table #tempped (datas int);

DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=5)
BEGIN
    PRINT @intFlag;

    insert into #tempped (datas)
    select @intFlag;

    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1;
END
GO
```

---

I considered the question to be an abstraction, if you are interested in performance then a `while` loop, recursive cte, or a cursor are not the most performant solution. Instead, use a numbers or tally table.

Further reading:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

Comment: thank you genius.. I will accept answer after 6 min.

Comment: @mohamedfaiz I would recommend considering the recustive CTE route instead especially if you will be doing any number of serious iterations. Generally you want to stay away from loop based operations and stick to SET based operations!

Comment: @Matt Depending on your definition of serious iterations, recursion is much slower than the other methods for generating a set, as demonstrated here: [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)

Comment: @SqlZim true that. I use tally tables all of the time and agree recursion can be very slow. all I was really thinking was if OP really only wanted 5 values than why not values (1),(2).... lol good edit!

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution using recursive CTE:

```
;WITH
    cte(datas) AS
    (
        SELECT      1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      datas + 1
        FROM        cte
        WHERE       datas < 5
    )

SELECT  datas
INTO    #tempped
FROM    cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with a `TALLY CTE`. This will work for up to 10K records...

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )

select N 
INTO #tempped
FROM cteTally
WHERE N <= 5


SELECT * FROM cteTally
SELECT * FROM #tempped
DROP TABLE #tempped
```

The good part about this is you can create a view with it... and never have to worry about this ever again. That is, you can just reference the view when ever you need a "Numbers Table" to join to.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

    WITH
        E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
        E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
        E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
        cteTally(N) AS 
        (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
        )
    select N from cteTally
    GO
```

Then, for your example, you would just do this:

```
SELECT  N
INTO    #tempped
FROM    cteTally
WHERE N <=5
```

[Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) original view...